# two databases need to access

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have two databases same server same domain and same username and password. I need away to select from the main DB and then the second DB I need to be able to connect to it and insert data.

this is currently what I am trying but it is not working.

```
public function publish(){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_detail WHERE approvedforsite = 2");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['customer_id'] . " - " .$row['TradingName'] . " - " . $row['Phone'] . " - " . $row['Street'] . " - " . $row['City'] . " - " . $row['State'] . " - " . $row['PostCode'] . " - " .$row['Description'];
            echo "<br />";  

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO realcas_incard_server.approved_business (customer_id, tradingname) 
                VALUES ('". $row['customer_id'] ."','".$row['TradingName']."')");


                mysql_query("INSERT INTO realcas_incard_server.business_stores (customer_id, storeid, phone, street, suburb, state, postcode, description) 
                VALUES ('". $row['customer_id'] ."', 1, '".$row['Phone']."', '" .$row['Street'] . "', '" . $row['City'] . "', '" . $row['State'] . "', '" . $row['PostCode'] . "','".$row['Description']."')");

                $offerresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  customer_realcash_offer WHERE businessid = ".$row['customer_id']);
                while($offers = mysql_fetch_array($offerresult))
                {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO _incard_server.Real_Cash_Offers (business_id,storeid,offer) VALUES (".$row['customer_id'].",1,'".$offers['offer']."')");   

                    echo $offers['offer']. "<br/>";
                }
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
```

Comment: "but it is not working" - is not an error description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `mysql_select_db()` to switch between databases on the same server/username/password/connection, or you can use the `database_name.table_name.column_name` dotted syntax (made easier with aliases, as in `select a.column from database_name.table_name as a`).

Those are your two options. (The third option is to just use one database, but I'm assuming that's not an option)

Answer (score 0):

say there is a table **test** in database **first**

test
id int

and table **junk** in database **second**

junk 
id int

then

query would be

**insert into junk(id) (select id from first.test);**